# Flutter UpperCamelCase

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I made my main.dart route to my splashscreen. In my main.dart, it accepted the name splashscreen() but in my splashscreen.dart it kept flagging the error "Name types using UpperCamelCase" when I named my class splashscreen.

Here is my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Routes/splashscreen.dart';

void main (){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp ({Key? key}) : super(key: key)
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "DoyarPay",

      home: splashscreen(),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my splashscreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class splashscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const splashscreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _splashscreenState createState() => _splashscreenState();
}

class _splashscreenState extends State<splashscreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}
```

On the splashscreen.dart it gives the "Name types using UpperCamelCase" error.
Can anyone help me out on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "accepted" but the warning indicates that you should follow some specific naming conventions. You should definetely check [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) which has more details about Effective Dart.

Answer (score 1):

For class name in dart, suggest using `CamelCase` means it will start with an uppercase letter and the next word's 1st letter will be uppercase as well.

In your case `splashscreen` which starts with `s` which is lowercase. Appropriate will be `SplashScreen`.

For file name, we use `snake_case`.  In this case `splashscreen.dart` will be `splash_screen.dart`

Learn more about

- [effective-dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style)
- [Camel case vs. snake case](https://www.theserverside.com/answer/Camel-case-vs-snake-case-Whats-the-difference#:%7E:text=When%20multiple%20words%20are%20used,between%20words%20to%20create%20separation.)

Answer (score 0):

Widgets always start with uppercase letter so change your splashscreen to Splashscreen, not only widgets but classes as well

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Routes/splashscreen.dart';

void main (){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp ({Key? key}) : super(key: key)
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "DoyarPay",

      home: Splashscreen(),
      
    );
  }
}
```

And your splashscreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    
    class Splashscreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const Splashscreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _SplashscreenState createState() => _SplashscreenState();
    }
    
    class _SplashscreenState extends State<Splashscreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes in dart has to be in UpperCamelCase.
Probably the linter doesn't detect the "error" (is not an error, you are just violating a convention) in your main.dart but it does during class declaration.

To follow dart standards just change the code using UpperCamelCase consistently:

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: "DoyarPay",

  home: SplashScreen(),
  
);


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea this was helpful, but i wanted my splashscreen to be read from another dart file

Comment: You can put the two in two different files and import the SplashScreen in you first file. Android Studio should help you